# Create Div via Javascript - Syntax Issues

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

EDIT: Directly below is the new code.  Below that is the original question.  I am asking for help for what is wrong with this code, as, in my week-old eyes, it seems fine.

```
function creatediv(){

    for (i=1;i<13;i++){
        var newcovdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newcovdiv.setAttribute('id',"cover_"+i);
        newcovdiv.style.width="900px";
        newcovdiv.style.height="25px";
        newcovdiv.style.position="relative";
        newcovdiv.style.left="0px";
        newcovdiv.style.top=(i-1)*25+"px";
        newcovdiv.style.background="#FFFFFF";
        newcovdiv.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('staff').appendChild(newcovdiv);
    }

    var newstaffdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newstaffdiv.setAttribute('id',"staff_sub");
    newstaffdiv.style.width="900px";
    newstaffdiv.style.height="300px";
    newstaffdiv.style.position="relative";
    newstaffdiv.style.left="0px";
    newstaffdiv.style.top="0px";
    newstaffdiv.style.backgroundImage="url(../images/staff_sub.png)";
    newstaffdiv.style.display="none";
    document.getElementbyId('staff').appendChild(newstaffdiv);

    for (i=13;i<101;i++){
        var newcovrdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newcovrdiv.setAttribute('id',"cover_"+i);
        newcovrdiv.style.width="900px";
        newcovrdiv.style.height="25px";
        newcovrdiv.style.position="relative";
        newcovrdiv.style.left="0px";
        newcovrdiv.style.top=(i-1)*25+"px";
        newcovrdiv.style.background="#FFFFFF";
        newcovrdiv.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('paper').appendChild(newcovrdiv);
    }

}
```

This place has been very helpful so far.

I've just started learning Javascript, and the syntax keeps getting me.  I've found an example of a javascript function that dynamically creates a div element, and I've tried to implement it in my code, but fault is found with it - but not by me.  I do not know where the code is bad.  Could someone point out what syntax (or worse) is wrong?

I call the function with

```
<body onload="creatediv()">
```

Here is the javascript function:

```
function creatediv(){

    for (i=1;i<13;i++){
        var newcovdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newcovdiv.setAttribute('id',"cover_"+i);
        newcovdiv.style.width=900;
        newcovdiv.style.height=25;
        newcovdiv.style.position="relative";
        newcovdiv.style.left=0;
        newcovdiv.style.top=(i-1)*25;
        newcovdiv.style.background="#FFFFFF";
        newcovdiv.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('staff').appendChild(newcovdiv);
    }

    var newstaffdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newstaffdiv.setAttribute('id',"staff_sub");
    newstaffdiv.style.width=900;
    newstaffdiv.style.height=300;
    newstaffdiv.style.position="relative";
    newstaffdiv.style.left=0;
    newstaffdiv.style.top=0;
    newstaffdiv.style.background-image="url(../images/staff_sub.png);
    newstaffdiv.style.display="none";
    document.getElementbyId('staff').appendChild(newstaffdiv);

    for (i=13;i<101;i++){
        var newcovrdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newcovrdiv.setAttribute('id',"cover_"+i);
        newcovrdiv.style.width=900;
        newcovrdiv.style.height=25;
        newcovrdiv.style.position="relative";
        newcovrdiv.style.left=0;
        newcovrdiv.style.top=(i-1)*25;
        newcovrdiv.style.background="#FFFFFF";
        newcovrdiv.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('paper').appendChild(newcovrdiv);
    }

}
```

There are already divs with the ids "paper" and "staff".  This is my first time using the appendChild thingy, so I thought the problem might be there.

This is bothersome.  I will be grateful to anyone who tries to lend me a hand.

Thanks much.

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` for you backgroung image which should be `backgroundImage`

Comment: You said `<body onload="creatediv()">` so where isthe creatediv() function?

Comment: You can start debuggin here http://www.jshint.com/. Just copy/paste your code and click lint to see the report. You have many errors.

Comment: @elclanrs I see many errors in jshint as well lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few obvious problems with your code:

1) You can't use background-image, because property names can't be hyphenated when using the dot form, also it's missing a ".

```
style.backgroundImage
```

2) All of the numeric type properties (top, left, width, height) are supposed to be css strings, so they all need to be converted to

```
style.width = '900px'
```

3) Your onload function calls creatediv(), however the function you posted is called letsgetiton, not sure if that's just because of the way you posted it or how it is in your actual code.

4) document.getElement**B**yId
Case matters

You might want to look at the Chrome developer tools or firebug in firefox. That error would have popped up straight away.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot.  I fixed the offending lines, but as expected it still won't work.  I try to test by putting an alert("TEXT"); in the function, so if the alert pops up then I know that we got into the function, at least.  I will edit my question to include the updated code.

Comment: Oh, wow!  This developer tools deal in Chrome is the bee's knees!  That's probably the most - long-term - helpful thing you could have said.

Comment: Oh, no, really, this is awesome.  This is amazing.  This is exactly what I needed.  I didn't know this developer tools thing existed, but it will speed up my work immensely.  Oh, this is grand, and so are you.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed two issues:

---

The following line of code is attempting to access an invalid property and does not have a closing quotation mark.

```
newstaffdiv.style.background-image="url(../images/staff_sub.png);
```

It should be like this:

```
newstaffdiv.style.backgroundImage="url(../images/staff_sub.png)";
```

---

You're calling the function `createDiv()`, yet the provided function is named `letsgetiton()`.

Comment: "style.background-image" is invalid.

Comment: Haha, yea, I changed the function name to post here, not wanting to seem too silly with such a name as letsgetiton().  In the actual code the call and the function are the same.